# Spring Boot: scanning components into an injectable list or set

Tags: spring-boot, component-scan

Spring Boot here. I have dozens and dozens of classes that are all subclass/implementations of the same interface:

```
public interface AnimalService {
    void eat();
    // etc.
}

@Component
public class DogService implements AnimalService {
    @Override
    public void eat() { return ... }

    // etc.
}

// many many many of these
```

I have a `@Service`-annotated class (`AnimalService`) that needs to be injected with each one of these subclasses:

```
@Service
public class AnimalProcessingService {

    @Autowired
    private List<AnimalService> allAnimalServices; // DogService, SharkService, etc.

    // the rest of the class definition is omitted intentionally

}
```

Now I *could* do this injection the hard way:

```
@Configuration
public class AnimalConfig {

    private DogService dogService;
    private SharkService sharkService;
    // ...etc.

    @Bean
    public List<AnimalService> allAnimalServices() {
        return Arrays.asList(dogService, sharkService /*, ...etc. */);
    }

}
```

But there's gotta be an easier way to do this, right?

How can inject this `List<AnimalService>` without having to manually create the list? Does this method allow you to filter out certain candidates (like if I just want a subset of the animal services)? Ideally something annotation-based (even if I have to define my own annotations) that works with Spring autowiring/DI/component scanning. Thanks for any and all help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're looking for `@ComponentScan`, which is a Spring (not Boot) annotation. It allows you to define a list of packages for Spring to scan for `@Components` (or "sub-annotations" such as `@Service`), to automatically instantiate beans of those classes and add them to the Spring context. So you can consider it a more automated way of the more manual `@Bean` method declaration.

Since you're using Spring Boot, however, you might want to look into `@SpringBootApplication` which, when used, enables component scan automatically. All you have to do is making sure your `@Component` classes are defined in the same package as, or sub-packages of, the `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class.

Once you've enabled component scanning, you can just inject a `List<AnimalService>` where you need it, like in a constructor, and do your processing (filtering?) there.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, so to your knowledge, Spring/Boot doesn't include a way to only inject a filtered subset of your components? You just inject the `List` and filter manually as needed? Thanks again!

Comment: No, to my knowledge there's no such filter mechanism available, and perhaps for good reasons. At some point you need to decide which types of beans to include and which to exclude. I imagine it makes the most sense to decide that at the location where they are injected/needed. I haven't tested this, but I think you can do some crude filtering by adding more interface layers between `AnimalService` and `DogService`, for example `QuadrupedService`, and then inject `List<QuadrupedService>`. But I can't really suggest much else without knowing your requirements.